# HTML and PHP about links on different folders using require_once

Tags: php, html

I'm still new to programming so basically I've got a navbar.php that I use to require_once in different pages.

Some of the links are in different folders, so after I click the link a second time it doesn't go where I want to.

An example of the links in my navbar.php

```
<li><a href="A.php">A</a></li>
<li><a href="B.php">B</a></li>
<li><a href="students/C.php">C</a></li>
<li><a href="teachers/D.php">D</a></li>
```

The result here is that the first time I click the C link it goes to
*localhost/test/students/C* and gets it right. But the second time I click it goes to 
*localhost/test/students/students/C.*

Are there any solutions aside from having a new navbar.php for each webpage?

Comment: `<li><a href="/students/C.php">C</a></li>
<li><a href="/teachers/D.php">D</a></li>`. Notice the first **`/`**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using differnt folders to link then you have to give the full link to achive this like below

`<li><a href="http://localhost/test/students/C.php">C</a></li>`